# Rails: Export arbitrary array to Excel using to_xls gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, export-to-excel

I want to export data from Rails to Excel in a way which:

- supports special characters (é, ô, ü etc.)
- works in all versions of Excel 2007+
- allows me to add calculated columns before export

I'm thinking about using the [to_xls](https://github.com/splendeo/to_xls) gem, but can't get it to work on arbitrary arrays (only Active Record objects).

The docs say the gem is only slightly oriented towards exporting Active Record sets, and that it's designed to transform arrays into Excel so it must be possible.

I think the issue is that it requires each object in the array to respond to .attributes.  I tried the approach of adding a virtual attribute to the Active Record model the export is based on but it seems that this doesn't show up when .attributes is called.

How could I get this working? (Or can you suggest an alternative way to achieve these goals?)

Comment: Can you show some code snippits?  It sounds like you're not far off.

Comment: @Dave I've tried all sorts. This is the simplest form that I feel should work, but I get a blank spreadsheet: [{foo: "1",bar: "2"}].to_xls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for arbitrary Arrays and for ActiveRecord objects. Apparently, the to_xls gem  supports all the customisation via the :columns and :headers parameters.

```
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'to_xls'

class Person
  attr_reader :first_name, :last_name

  def initialize(first_name, last_name)
    @first_name = first_name
    @last_name  = last_name
  end

  def name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
end

array = [Person.new("Andrzej", "Krzywda"), Person.new("Derek", "Hill")]

File.open("output.xls", "w") do |f|
  f.write(
    array.to_xls(
      :columns => [:first_name, :last_name, :name],
      :headers => ["First name", "Last name", "name"]
    )
  )
end
```

Comment: This works perfectly and is very helpful.  Do you know how you would incorporate a virtual attribute into the attributes hash on an Active Record object?

Comment: I'm glad I could help. It was my first answer on SO :) I extended my answer with the Rails example.

Comment: Thanks.  That last bit didn't work for me though.  I got "undefined method `name' for #<Person:0x007fde0bc52d58>"

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'm going to wait a bit before accepting the answer if that's ok just to see if there are any alternative approaches to this problem.

Comment: The current solution is the simplest I could find.

Comment: I'm just wondering if anybody has any totally different takes on the problem.  Generating arbitrary TSVs is so easy with CSV.generate(col_sep: "\t") do |csv|... but then I found all sorts of problems with encoding and compatibility with different versions of Excel.  Ideally there would be a way of doing .to_xls on one of these arrays.

Comment: With my latest update, it is just a call to to_xls on one of those arrays. My previous attempt with overwriting .attributes was wrong/complicated.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26855/discussion-between-andrzej-krzywda-and-derek-hill)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [axlsx](https://github.com/randym/axlsx)? According to the [examples section](https://github.com/randym/axlsx#examples) it should work with generic arrays.

Comment: Thanks.  I had a look at it axlsx, and it could be a good option.  However I started with to_xls because it seemed simpler and suitable for my needs.  A complication here is that my app is on Heroku so you can't create a file that saves to the filesystem.  Looking at the examples now they all seem quite involved in terms of formatting etc.  What I need to know is how to get a basic array out of Rails on the fly.

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned [axlsx_rails](https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails) too.